# Unity: Error CS1041 on line 5: Identifier expected: 'public' is a keyword?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have been following the Unity3D **Procedural Cave Generation**, but I found an error very early on in *MapGeneration.cs*. Unity says that on line 1 word 1, there is an error: *Identifier expected: 'public' is a keyword*. I cannot see any difference from my code and the tutorial's code. Here is the link to the tutorial video: [[\Tutorial video 1]](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/advanced/scripting/procedural-cave-generation-pt1?playlist=17153) and here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System

public class MapGeneration : MonoBehaviour {

    public int width;
    public int height;

    public string seed;
    public bool useRandomSeed;

    [Range(0,100)]
    public int randomFillPercent;

    int[,] map;

    void Start() {
        GenerateMap();
    }

    void GenerateMap() {
        map = new int[width,height];
    }

    void RandomFillMap() {
        if (useRandomSeed) {
            seed = Time.time.ToString();
        }

        System.Random psuedoRandom = new System.Random(seed.GetHashCode());

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
                map[x,y] = (psuedoRandom.Next(0,100) < randomFillPercent)? 1: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos() {
        if (map != null) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
                    Gizmos.color = (map[x,y] == 1)? Color.black: Color.white;
                    Vector3 position = new Vector3(-width/2 + x + .5f,0,-height/2 + y + .5f);
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(position,Vector3.one);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is **public** on line one.

Comment: In the question you say line 1, however it is on line 5 (like you say in the heading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the `;` after `using System` (that, maybe, is also an incomplete import).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed it instantly!